# Import JSON to OrientDB type document using ETL

Tags: json, import, etl, orientdb

How can I import some json files to OrientDB to use it like document type (not graph)?

My data is something like this:

```
    {
    "p_partkey": 1,
    "p_name": "lace spring",
    "lineorder": [{
        "customer": [{
            "c_name": "Customer#000014704"
        }],
        "lo_quantity": 49,
        "lo_orderpriority": "1-URGENT",
        "lo_discount": 3,
        "lo_shipmode": "RAIL|",
        "lo_tax": 0
    }, {
        "customer": [{
            "c_name": "Customer#000026548"
        }],
        "lo_quantity": 15,
        "lo_orderpriority": "3-MEDIUM",
        "lo_discount": 10,
        "lo_shipmode": "SHIP|",
        "lo_tax": 0
    }]
}
```

and I create a configfile.json like under to import but it dont work:

```
{
  "config": {
    "log": "debug"
  },
  "source" : {
    "file": { "path": "/home/raphael/Documents/data/part/part1.json", "lock" : true }
  },
  "extractor" : {
    "json": {}
  },
  "transformers" : [
   { "merge": { "joinFieldName":"p_partkey"} },
   { "vertex": { "class": "part"} }
  ],
  "loader" : {
    "orientdb": {
      "dbURL": "plocal:/opt/orientdb/databases/part",
      "dbUser": "root",
      "dbPassword": "rasns1901",
      "dbAutoCreate": true,
      "tx": false,
      "batchCommit": 1000,
      "dbType": "document",
      "classes": [
        {"name": "part", "extends": "V"}
      ],      
      "indexes": [
        {"class":"part", "fields":["p_partkey:integer"], "type":"UNIQUE_HASH_INDEX" }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

There's something wrong with my configfile? Theres no example of it on OrientDB documents.

Comment: Hi, is the data json that you posted complete? I'm trying to reproduce your situation but it seams it's missing something

Comment: @IvanMainetti  That sample was a invalid json, I've corrected it on the post. But my data is correct. Thanks.

Comment: @Raphael, the json config refers to "p_partkey" while in the sample data this field isn't present at all.

Comment: @Raphael In your configfile.json your database is of type document and then class "part" can't extend V, because the class V not exist.

Comment: @RobertoFranchini, I've added the p_partkey to the sample.

Comment: @AlessandroRota, should I only remove the extends. Do you have a example of config of this kind?

Comment: @Raphael, I have found this link 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/orient-database/pZidVwulKes  
Hope it helps.

Comment: @AlessandroRota Thanks, ill try it.

Comment: @AlessandroRota, I've made it using python. I gave up using the ETL. Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up using the ETL and did it using python, it was easier.

Here goes my code:

```
from __future__ import division
import csv
import sys
import collections
import pyorient

def Inicio():


    db_name = "db"
    client = pyorient.OrientDB("127.0.0.1", 2424)
    session_id = client.connect( "admin", "admin" )
    client.db_open( db_name, "admin", "admin" )
    i=1
    while i<3:
        file= open('home/Desktop/part'+str(i)+'.json','rd')
        texto = file.readline()
        co = 'INSERT INTO part CONTENT '+texto 
        client.command(co)
        print("Inserted:"+str(i))
        file.close()
        i=i+1
    client.db_close()

Inicio()
```

The only thing you have to pay atention is that my json file dont have carriage returns, so the readline() function works.